Layout problem in Flutter, text clipping and alignment
I want to display a row that has the following content:

Aligned to the left of the row: an icon and a text inside a container. NB: I don't want to use the standard Chip() widget.
Aligned to the right of the row: a button.

If the width of the screen is to small, the text has to be clipped (ending with ellipsis).
If there's enough screen width, then 1) and 2) should only take the space they need; not taking the full available space. In other words, the space between 1) and 2) should be empty.
I prefer not to use the IntrinsicWidth for performance reasons.
The following code example is made for test purposes:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Flexible(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.yellow,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Icon(Icons.info),
                Flexible(
                  child: Text(
                    'This text might be clipped',
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),

        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text('Button'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

The result is this:

That looks ok. But when I have more screen width it looks like this:

That's not what I want. The button should be aligned to the right.
I've tried solving it with using a Spacer() in between the container and the button. I then get this:

The result is that the Spacer() takes too much space. There's enough space for the text, but unfortunately it's now clipped.
How can I solve this?

just add mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, to first Row
class MyLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Flexible(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.yellow,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Icon(Icons.info),
                Flexible(
                  child: Text(
                    'This text might be clipped',
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text('Button'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


I think this works with one small change: mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min should be mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max for the first Row.

i tried on DartPad and it worked with min

but I think would be better remove it and use default one - max, you're right

This works. Thanks!

If I got you right you want something like that:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: DecoratedBox(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.yellow,
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Icon(Icons.info),
                Flexible(
                  child: Text(
                    'This text might be clipped',
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text('Button'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

That will force your text to fill as much space as it can.

As I said in my question, it should only take the space it needs. With Expanded it takes all available space, which I don't want. I changed the question a bit to make this more clear.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Use Expanded for that purpose. In the Row where to button is, wrap the Container within Expanded like this:
class MyLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        // add Expanded here
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.yellow,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Icon(Icons.info),
                Flexible(
                  child: Text(
                    'This text might be clipped',
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text('Button'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}



As I said in my question, it should only take the space it needs. With Expanded it takes all available space, which I don't want. I changed the question a bit to make this more clear.

@Marc I see, I won't edit my answer because the solution by Nagual seems to work with one little change, see my comment at Nagual's answer.
